# Why wordpress can't display the bash command properly?

Tags: html

Wordpress version:4.7.5.

test1 contain only one bash command before publlish.

sort    -k2,2 -k1,1 < people.txt

It display as below.

[image]

test2 contain tha same bash command before publlish,just write `< people.txt` as `<people.txt`,no blank between `<` and `p`.

`sort    -k2,2 -k1,1 <people.txt`

It display as below.

Maybe it is a bug for wordpress?

[image]

Comment: 1. this is a wordpress development site, not a support forum. 2. it should work, and if it is not you should open a bug. 3. you probably have some problem with a plugin, or you use the text editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a post gets published, it runs `the_content()` through a filter to strip out unsafe HTML. It looks like the parser thinks `<people.txt` is malformed HTML and strips it out.

Change `<` to `&lt;`, which is the HTML entity for `<`, and you should be able to publish the post and view it properly on the front end.